# How to answer Calculus by Michael Spivak Chapter 5 Problem 30.II

Tags: calculus

> Prove that
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(|x|) = \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$$

What I did is:

Say $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = L$

That means:

> $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists \delta >0 $ / if   $ 0<x<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$

If $x = |y|$ then:

$\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists \delta >0 $ / if  $ 0<|y|<\delta$ then $|f(|y|)-L| < \epsilon$

Which actually means

$$\lim_{y\to 0}f(|y|) = L$$

Is my demonstration correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just one direction has been proved. For the other direction, let  $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f(|x|)=M$, then given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ with $0<|x|<\delta$, then $|f(|x|)-M|<\epsilon$.

Then for all $z$ with $0<z<\delta$, we have $0<|z|=z<\delta$, so $|f(z)-M|<\epsilon$, this shows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^{+}}f(x)=M$.

Comment: Isn't my proof aplicable for both directions?

Comment: I will say no, since you have assumed first that the existence of $x\rightarrow 0^{+}$ to prove the second one, but the philosophy is almost the same.